# Import xml into MS Project Professional 2013

Tags: xml, import, ms-project

Please can someone help me? I'm trying to import xml files from an application to MS Projects Professional 2013, as I want to change platforms. When I start importing the xml file I get the error message

An input error occurred
The element  in the  element with  = 222 has invalid data

Is there any way round this? I have loads of files. I can open the project but can't publish it to Project server, possibly due to the error message.

Please help.

Kind Regards
Oje

Comment: Without the data it will be hard to tell what's the issue

Comment: milz what data do you need? I'm not allowed to post images yet

Comment: Well, your error message states "The element in the element with = 222 has invalid data", so it's telling you what element has invalid data. So, without the relevant section of the original file, it will be hard to tell you what's the issue. However, I will go out on a limb and say that your issue is probably related with some special character (like `'`).

Comment: Thank you milz. I'll go through the data. Would you have any idea why I'm struggling to publish to project online from project professional 2013? I established the link earlier and could publish. But that option does not show up anymore. Instead I have the option of sharing via the sharepoint site